# How to create a checkedtextview in android programatically?

Tags: java, android, checkedtextview

In android I am trying to add a checktextview using this:

```
CheckedTextView checkedtextview = new CheckedTextView(this, null, 
    android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple);
checkedtextview.setText(personobj.lastname + ", " + personobj.firstname);
LocationLayout.addView(checkedtextview);
```

But when I test this, it only shows the text and I don't see the checkbox. Does anyone know how to display the checkbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You forgot to set the checkmark drawable to the `CheckedTextView` - it doesn't have one by default. Call one of the following two methods on the view to set one:

- `setCheckMarkDrawable(Drawable d)`
- `setCheckMarkDrawable(int resid)`

Unfortunately the default checkmark drawables are not in Android's public name space, and thus not directly accessible. You should be able to resolve the theme's `checkMark` attribute though and set that. The code to do so would look somewhat like this:

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
// you'll probably want to use your activity as context here:
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.checkMark, value, true);
int checkMarkDrawableResId = value.resourceId;
// now set the resolved check mark resource id:
checkedtextview.setCheckMarkDrawable(checkMarkDrawableResId);
```

Comment: android.R.attr.checkMark didn't work for me but using android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple gave me the standard checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use setChecked(true) to make it checked.  But this isn't a checkbox, if you want that use android.widget.CheckBox instead.